Why is the order of CLI messages different from the code in R
I have come across rather weird behavior when using the cli package to print Command Line messages. Please see the simple example below:
library(cli)


test_cli_orders <- function() {
  
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
  cli_progress_step(msg = "Doing 1", msg_done = "1 is done")
  
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
  cli_progress_step(msg = "Doing 2", msg_done = "2 is done")
  
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
  cli_text("I should be displayed last...")
  
}

When running this function,
test_cli_orders()

I'd expect the text of cli_text to appear after "2 is done" from the last cli_progress_step, but it yields:

It is very confusing, and I have no idea what caused it after many experiments. I'd greatly appreciate your thoughts.

This is because your cli_text at the end is considered as a progress of previous cli_progress. You can end it by cli_progress_done before printing your text.
library(cli)


test_cli_orders <- function() {
  
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
  cli_progress_step(msg = "doing 1", msg_done = "1 is done")
  
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
  cli_progress_step(msg = "Doing 2", msg_done = "2 is done")
  
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
  cli_progress_done()
  
  cli_text("I should be displayed last...")
  
}

test_cli_orders()



would  fflush work here?

@CarlWitthoft Sorry I'm not familiar with that.

sorry, in R it's  just  flush(con)    (fflush is a  csh / sh  / ksh command)
